# Regex Substitution to remove duplicates

Tags: regex

I have a regex which, due to the source data, always captures the word or phrase twice in a row e.g.

```
Word Word
```

or

```
Word1 Word2 Word1 Word2
```

I was looking for a substitution string to try to identify the duplicate so I could end up with

```
Word
Word1 Word2
```

And thought perhaps there is just a way to capture 1/2 the characters minus 1? So in the case of `Word1 Word2 Word1 Word2` it would capture the (23-1)/2 first characters. Barring that I'd want to identify the part of the string that repeats the first word and substitute for that.

Comment: What is your regex?

Comment: The regex itself is sort of unimportant, the relevant part however uses a capture group `(<?P<Term>.*?)` with a pattern around it. My plan/need is to do a substitution on the term which again due to the nature of the source will always be a duplicated word or term.

Comment: Please post the code you have, now, the question is just unclear.

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: What is the desired result if you have `Word1 Word2 Word1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This replaces the duplicates:

`s/(\s*\b\w+\b\s*) (?=.*\b\1\b)//`

https://regex101.com/r/9VRGp5/1

-edit- added the spaces as mentioned by @user3649739

Comment: This will find "dupes" that are not adjacent to each other.

Comment: Then I think I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Doqnach Actually for my purposes it is perfect. I just changed it to 'trim' the results like so `(\s*\b\w+\b\s*) (?=.*\b\1\b)`

Answer (score -1):

In Python you can use the following regex:

```
text = """
Word Word
Word1 Word2 Word1 Word2
"""
>>> re.sub(r'(\b\w+\b)(?=[\s\S]*?\b\1\b)', '', text)
'\n Word\n  Word1 Word2\n'
```

The explanation:

```
(\b\w+\b)     # matching the letters with word boundaries
(?=           # positive lookahead
  [\s\S]*?    # lazy match zero or more whitespace and non-whitespace characters
  \b\1\b      # matching the SAME word, as found before
)
```

This regex will leave the latest word.

---

Debuggex:

```
(\b\w+\b)(?=[\s\S]+?\b\1\b)
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vaqoBugnGTbxtdjs)